# Newbie, cant use scanf() to parse input, simple code included

Tags: c

I have a problem with my code. It should be parsing inputs like

> 1 34 a 2 -5 67 c

or

> 3455 124 -123 111 s 123 3544 f g

Or any other mix of characters (of length 1) and numbers. Here is my code:

```
char oper = 0;
int number = 0;
do{
    if(scanf("%d", &number)==1)
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        scanf("%c", &oper);
        if(oper == 'g')
        {
            ...
        }
        if(oper == 'h')
        {
            ...
        }
        ... 
    } 
} while(oper != '\n');
```

When it gets to a character the `scanf("%c", &oper);` copies "\n" into `oper` and I want it to be "a" or "s"

What is going wrong, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: I don't understand the requirement.  can you elaborate?

Comment: I cant get characters into oper variable

Comment: *`if(oper == 'g') ...`* Now would be a good time to look at the `switch`/`case` construct. Not that this code is *wrong*, but an experienced c programmer would likely find it non-idomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scanf("%d" ...) will scan past white space (blank, tab, newline) to get to the number.

scanf("%c" ...) will read the next character.

You need to figure out a way to scan past white space. Have you looked at the definitions for the formats to scanf?

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string) seems quite helpful compared to normal man pages.

Comment: Yes i have looked. Didnt know that whitespace char is interpreted as "/n"

Comment: You could use `isspace` to reject characters that are whitespace. See `man isspace` for some other nice functions.

Comment: Otherwise, go with the Wikipedia link of @gbulmer.

Comment: @Tomáš Šíma - did you mean to write "Didn't know that '\n' is interpreted as white space"? Otherwise what do you mean?